# Incompatible dependencies after updating Spring Boot version from 2.1.3 to 2.3.11

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to update Spring Boot version to 2.3.11 from 2.1.3. After I update it in pom like below

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.11.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

an error occurs:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator.

It looks some dependencies are incompatible with spring 2.3.11. Is there any way to find the dependencies that are incompatible?

Comment: Have you read the upgrade guides?

Comment: @khmarbaise not yet. I'm new to maven and spring.

Answer (score 0):

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Upgrade 2.6.6 maybe your problem resolve and I am using it there is not such problem like this.